# Rules not work in jQuery validate function

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-validate

I don't know what's wrong with my code. I am newbie to jQuery validate function,
I wanna use `'required'` value `'true'` or `'false'` dynamically for add and edit page separately. I want field `'cate_image'` set to 'not required' in edit page as already have an image which is being inserted in 'add' page but need to validate only image format using '`accept`'. help me out.

```
if($("#hidden_cate_id").val() > 0){
  var tf = "false";
}else{
  var tf = "true";
}

$("#form-addcategory").validate(
  {
    rules: {
      cate_name: { required: true },
      cate_image: { required: tf, accept: "image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png" }
    },
    messages: {
      cate_name: { required: "Category name is required" },
      cate_image: { required: "Category image is required" }
    },
  });
```

i put `if` condition for edit page if `$("#hidden_cate_id").` exist `tf` value will `false` and only check for `accept` rule. but it doesn't works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change :

```
if($("#hidden_cate_id").val() > 0){
  var tf = "false";
}else{
  var tf = "true";
}
```

To :

```
if($("#hidden_cate_id").val() > 0){
  var tf = false; 
}else{
  var tf = true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($("#hidden_cate_id").val() > 0){
  var tf = "false"; // pass boolean value false
}else{
  var tf = "true"; // pass boolean value true
}
```

in this condition you are passing true and false value as a string

```
 rules: {
      cate_name: { required: true },
      cate_image: { required: tf, accept: "image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png" } // tf as a boolean value
    },
    messages: {
      cate_name: { required: "Category name is required" },
      cate_image: { required: "Category image is required" }
    },
```

here in validate your accessing those value like boolean